# How can I combine a large CROSS JOIN query and return 1 result?

Tags: postgresql

I have a rather large PostgresSQL query that returns a single JSON result that is then sent to the front-end app for display:

```
Select * FROM (SELECT sum(subscribers) AS subscribers FROM plans WHERE userid=$1 AND startDate>=$2 AND startDate<$3) subscribers
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(status) AS inactivesubscribers FROM subscribers WHERE userid=$1 AND status='inactive' OR status='suspended') inactivesubs
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(planName) AS plans FROM plans WHERE userid=$1 AND status='active') plans
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(promoCode) AS promotionals FROM promotionals WHERE userid=$1 AND status='active' AND startDate>=$2 AND startDate<$3) promotionals
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(chargeDate) AS charges FROM transactions WHERE userid=$1 AND chargeDate>=$2 AND chargeDate<$3) charges
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(refundDate) AS refunds FROM transactions WHERE userid=$1 AND refundDate>=$2 AND refundDate<$3) refunds
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(sentDate) AS messages FROM messages WHERE userid=$1 AND sentDate>=$2 AND sentDate<$3) messages
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(templateName) AS activetemplates FROM templates WHERE userid=$1 AND status='active') activetemplates
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(templateName) AS inactivetemplates FROM templates WHERE userid=$1 AND status='suspended') inactivetemplates
```

Returns:

```
[
  {
    subscribers: '146',
    inactivesubscribers: '12',
    plans: '12',
    promotionals: '12',
    charges: '7',
    refunds: '12',
    messages: '5',
    activetemplates: '4',
    inactivetemplates: '4' 
  }
]
```

But, I'm not sure how I can add this query to gather 6 of the most popular plans within the large query:

```
CROSS JOIN (SELECT planName,subscribers as popularplans FROM plans WHERE userid=$1 AND status='active' ORDER BY subscribers DESC LIMIT 6) popularplans
```

Due to the `CROSS JOIN` instructions, the query above doesn't work as intended, because the query creates 6 different object results with `planname: plan x` and `popularplans: x` on each found row.

```
[
      {
        subscribers: '146',
        inactivesubscribers: '12',
        planname: 'Plan 1',
        plans: '12',
        popularplans: '22',
        promotionals: '12',
        charges: '7',
        refunds: '12',
        messages: '5',
        activetemplates: '4',
        inactivetemplates: '4' 
     },
     {
        subscribers: '146',
        inactivesubscribers: '12',
        planname: 'Plan 2',
        plans: '12',
        popularplans: '12',
        promotionals: '12',
        charges: '7',
        refunds: '12',
        messages: '5',
        activetemplates: '4',
        inactivetemplates: '4' 
     }
     ...etc
 ]
```

Ideally, I want the large query to return a single JSON object and be structured like so:

```
[
  {
    subscribers: '146',
    inactivesubscribers: '12',
    plans: '12',
    popularplans: [
      { planName: 'Plan 1', subscribers: '22' },
      { planName: 'Plan 2', subscribers: '12' },
      ...etc
    ],
    promotionals: '12',
    charges: '7',
    refunds: '12',
    messages: '5',
    activetemplates: '4',
    inactivetemplates: '4' 
  }
]
```

Is there a better or a different approach to the large query than tons of cross joins?

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [`jsonb_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html), and [`jsonb_build_object(k,v)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT json_agg(jsonb_build_object('plan', planName, 'count', subscribers) ORDER BY subscribers DESC) as popularplans 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM plans
    WHERE userid=$1 AND status='active'
    FETCH FIRST 6 ROWS ONLY
  )
) popularplans
```

Comment: Very close! Unfortunately, it's returning all the records (not adhering to the 6 limit) and it's returning the records in this format: `[{ plan 1: 22, plan 2: 12 ...etc]}`, when it should be `[{ planname: 'plan 1', subscribers: '12' },{  planname: 'plan 2': subscribers: '12'`} ...etc ]`

Comment: I was able to fix the naming convention, but the limit still doesn't work. The fix for the naming was: `jsonb_build_object('plan', planName, 'count', subscribers)`

Comment: @MFC88 see the update

Comment: Very close again, but the order was incorrect due to the `ORDER BY` being in the statement. However, I was able to make your solution work with a bit of tweaking. See my answer.

Comment: Typo: The `ORDER BY` was in the wrong statement. I'll be using your modified answer since it seems the most efficient. Thank you for your help!!! It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With the help and guidance of @Evan Carroll pointing me in the right direction, I was able to work out two solutions:

```
CROSS JOIN (

  // gathers and filters plans by userid and status
  WITH filtered_plans_table AS (
    SELECT planName,subscribers 
    FROM plans 
    WHERE userid=$1 AND status='active'
  )

  // aggregates and returns a "popularplans" JSON object from the "top_6_plans" below
  SELECT json_agg(filtered_plans) as popularplans 

  // reorders and limits the "filtered_table_plans" to 6 records
  FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM filtered_plans_table 
    ORDER BY subscribers DESC 
    LIMIT 6
  ) 
  AS top_6_plans 

) t
```

OR

```
CROSS JOIN (
  // aggregates and returns a "popularplans" JSON object from the "filtered_plans_table" below
  SELECT json_agg(filtered_plans_table) as popularplans

  // filters, reorders and limits to 6 records
  FROM (
    SELECT planName,subscribers 
    FROM plans WHERE userid=$1 AND status='active' 
    ORDER BY subscribers DESC 
    LIMIT 6
  ) as filtered_plans_table

) popularplans
```

Result:

```
 [ 
   {
     subscribers: '146',
     inactivesubscribers: '12',
     plans: '12',
     popularplans: [ 
       { planname: 'Plan 1', subscribers: '22' },
       { planname: 'Plan 2', subscribers: '12' }, 
       { planname: 'Plan 3', subscribers: '11' }, 
       { planname: 'Plan 4', subscribers: '10' }, 
       { planname: 'Plan 5', subscribers: '8' }, 
       { planname: 'Plan 6', subscribers: '6' }, 
     ],
     promotionals: '12',
     charges: '7',
     refunds: '12',
     messages: '5',
     activetemplates: '4',
     inactivetemplates: '4' 
  } 
]
```